# How to show friend photo using graph api facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i try to use graph api facebook , but, i have problem with showing profile picture of friend. this is my code

```
function getPhoto()
    {
        FB.api("/"+ userId +"/picture", {
                "redirect": false,
                "height": "200",
                "type": "normal",
                "width": "200"
            }, function (response) {

                //userIds = response.authResponse.;
                var user = "";
                 for(var i = 0 ; i < response.data.length ; i++)
                    user += showScore(response.data.url);

                console.log("photo :"+ response.data.url);
                //console.log("photo f :"+ response.authResponse.user.id);
                console.log("photo f :"+ response.data.friends);

                //$("#score").html(user);
            }
        );
    }
```

please help me, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
GET /me/friends?fields=picture
```

to be able to get the friend's pictures. But be aware that starting with Graph API v2.0, only those friends will be returned which also use the same app the requesting access token was generated with.

Comment: i already use  FB.api("/"+ userId +"/picture" but it didnt work

Comment: You didn't use my example! And what does "didn't work" mean? An error message, or is the result just empty? Then no friends use the same app, as I explained.